# 'list index out of range' error with list - dictionary values

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I created this program that 'plants' tomatoes and assigns them a date of ripening (by units of turns). However, when I try to use that date, the system returns the error 'list index out of range.' I cannot for the life of me understand why this is happening. Please understand that I am a beginner programmer, so while I did truly look for an answer to this problem, much of what I found was complete gibberish to me. Thanks!

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# this code is meant for testing a portion of farmboi simulator.
# this code is not the entire program.

tomato_seeds = 2
tomato_planted = 0
tomato = 0
tomato_id = 0
growing = {}  # keeps track of what items are currently growing
grown = []
turn = 0  # keeps track of what turn the player is on


# actually 'plants' the tomatoes

def plant(crop, amount):  # the error only runs when amount > 1
    global tomato_seeds
    global tomato_planted
    global tomato_id
    global growing
    global grown
    if crop == 'tomato':
        for i in range(amount):
            if tomato_seeds > 0:
                tomato_seeds -= 1
                tomato_planted += 1
                growing['tomato_' + str(tomato_id)] = turn + 5  
                # this creates a library that contains tomatoes and their turn of harvest
                grown.append('tomato_' + str(tomato_id))  
                # this list is so I can run a for loop using numbers (there's probably a better way to do this idk)
                tomato_id += 1
    else:
        print('You do not have any tomato seeds remaining\n')
        print(str(grown))
        print(str(growing))


# checks every loop to see if the tomatoes are ripe

def check_harvest():
    global tomato
    global tomato_planted
    harvested = 0
    for item in range(len(growing)):
        print('checker: ' + str(growing[grown[item]]))
        if growing[grown[item]] == turn:  
        # Im calling the value here the checker (this is also where the error occurrs)
            tomato += 1
            tomato_planted -= 1
            del growing[grown[item]]
            del grown[item]
        if harvested > 0:
            print('You have harvested ' + str(harvested) + ' tomatoes')


while True:
    if input('What would you like to do?\n').lower() == 'plant':
        plant('tomato', 2)

    check_harvest()
    turn += 1
    print('turn: ' + str(turn))
```

(There might be an indentation error somewhere, disregard this. I was having trouble with putting it into the stack overflow text box as code)

Comment: could you please write the error here?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/cavem/Documents/Python/Personal Python Files/Farmboi Simulator/Farmboi test.py", line 52, in <module>
    check_harvest()
  File "C:/Users/cavem/Documents/Python/Personal Python Files/Farmboi Simulator/Farmboi test.py", line 38, in check_harvest
    print("checker: " + str(growing[grown[item]]))
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: @JakeShropshire I was able to run your code without any issues. The 2 functions were charged and the while loop was run correctly. The out of range came when I ran the plant the sixth time (see enclosed picture https://i.stack.imgur.com/VpQkp.png)

Answer (score 1):

In function `check_harvest()` the length of the `growing` dictionary may not be the same as the length of the `grown` list.

`plant()` will add `amount` items to `growing`, however, only one item is added to `grown`. So, if `amount` is greater than one, the dictionary and list lengths will diverge.

Then `check_harvest()` iterates over the length of `growing` which could be longer than `grown`, which results in an attempt to access an item in `grown` beyond the limits of the list.

It might solve the problem if you indented the two lines:

```
            grown.append("tomato_" + str(tomato_id)) #this list is so I can run a for loop using numbers (there's probably a better way to do this idk)
            tomato_id += 1
```

such that they are within the for loop:

```
            for i in range(amount):
                if tomato_seeds > 0:
                    tomato_seeds -= 1
                    tomato_planted += 1
                    growing["tomato_" + str(tomato_id)] = turn + 5 #this creates a library that contains tomatoes and their turn of harvest
                    grown.append("tomato_" + str(tomato_id)) #this list is so I can run a for loop using numbers (there's probably a better way to do this idk)
                    tomato_id += 1
```

but I can't be sure as I don't really understand your code.

Comment: The indentation error was an issue with my copying onto stack overflow. I don't suppose I understand what you mean that the dictionary and the list aren't growing/depleting at the same rate. I thought that the .append() method did the same thing as declaring a new item in a dictionary (I very well could be wrong). I was a little concerned about using the del function, so is it possible that the issue is there?

Comment: @JakeShropshire: then you should fix the indentation in your question. The error can be explained by the code that you've posted, but if that is not the code that you are running, then it's unproductive to make further guesses. Also, the exception should be added to the question and formatted correctly (as code).